# Subselect fails, but as view it works

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I was hoping to run a single query and get results from that. However, MSSQL complains about a syntax error near the `GROUP` key word.
I was hoping to do the following.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,Field_2
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Field_1, Field_2 
            FROM Table_1)
GROUP BY Field_2 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Instead I had to create a view, View_1, with the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field_1, Field_2 
  FROM Table_1
```

And then do a

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, Field_2
    FROM View_1
GROUP BY Field_2 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The question is why, to my mind it is essentially the same SQL.

Note: Field, table and view names have been changed to protect the innocent. ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQL Server requires you to specify a table alias for a derived table/inline view:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
         x.Field_2
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Field_1, Field_2 
            FROM Table_1) AS x
GROUP BY x.Field_2 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: To be fair, SQL Server cannot be blamed for this bad language design because it is specified in Standard SQL-92. In his writings, [Hugh Darwen](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Importance-of-Column-Names.pdf) always employs a pejorative table correlation name (something else from SQL-92; 'alias' is colloquial :) such as `TEETH_GNASHER`.

Answer (score 0):

OMG Ponies' answer is 100% correct.

I think that this will show same results but I can't test now:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Field_1) AS cnt
     , Field_2
FROM Table_1
GROUP BY Field_2 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Field_1) > 1
```